# Ordering tests using trial twisted

Tags: python, testing, twisted

We are thinking of using trial from twisted for our testing. Looking at the documentation, there does not seem to be a way to order the tests specifically, it follows its own based on names. Is there any way to order the tests without using naming conventions?

Comment: You can randomize the order with --random.  If that's not good enough, maybe explain what order you want and why.

Comment: I want to be able to go in a specific order. What I am looking for is to create test cases separately, and then create a suite with each of these.

As an example, I want to create five separate py files for 5 test cases, and then create a suite out of those 5, in any order I want to execute the tests in. Suite can contain 1,4,5,3,2 for example. Or 1,3,5.Is that doable?

Comment: Why do you want them to go in a specific order?

Comment: Because I want operations to happen in a specific order, and in some cases, mix and match. Create some data first, read it back, and keep that data, and then fail some components and check if the data can still be read or modified etc..

Comment: Is specifying an ordering possible in trial?

Comment: Tests are meant to be independent and isolated.  trial goes to a great deal of effort to achieve this and to help you achieve this.  Since making tests depend on each other is the opposite of this, it doesn't go to any effort to help you create a particular ordering.  Nope, it's not possible to specify an ordering in trial.

Answer (score 0):

One can only order `alphabetically` or "`toptobottom`" (which executes your tests in the order they're in the code) using `trial --order`.  So if you wanted to execute the tests based on the order they're written in your code, then you'd execute something similar to:

```
trial --order=toptobottom myunittests.py
```

This is the extent of `trial`'s ordering functionality though. You may be able to use `py.test` for some other kinds of ordering, but I have now clue how to do that.